# Basic Confusion on Push-Forward of a Measure

Tags: measure-theory, density-function, change-of-variable, pushforward

Let $\rho:\mathbb{R}^d\to \mathbb{R}$ be a probability density on $\mathbb{R}^d$. Let $f:\mathbb{R}^d\to \mathbb{R}^d $ be invertible. Consider the push-forward of $\rho$ by $f$, denoted $f_{\#}\rho$, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure#Main_property:_change-of-variables_formula).

My question is the integral of $f_{\#}\rho$ always 1 ? And is $f_{\#}\rho$ guaranteed to be a density (i.e absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure ?

Comment: What are the regularity conditions on $f$?

Comment: If $(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^d),\mu)$ is a Borel probability measure and $f:(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^n))\rightarrow(R,\mathscr{R})$ is measurable, then the push forward $\mu_f(A):=\mu(f^{-1}(A)$, $A\in\mathscr{R}$ is always a probability measure. This so this  holds in the particular case  $\mu=\phi(x)\,dx$ with $0\leq\phi$ and $\int\phi=1$.

Comment: for the first statement [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3826120/121671) is a post. As for the later, that is the change of variable formula in multivariate Calculus. A rigors proof can be found in Rudin's book an Real compass analysis, or Folland's book on integration.

Comment: Edit: In particular, if $f$ a diffemorphism on $\mathbb{R}^d$, then $\mu_f(dx)=\phi(f(x))\,|J_f(x)|\,dx$, where $J_f$ is the determinant of the derivative of $f$.

Comment: @OliverDiaz, I think you need to replace $f$ by $f^{-1}$ in your formula, don't you?

Comment: @Ruy: maybe so, i am not at my desk to read carefully, but in any case the idea is the same.

Answer (score 12):

First of all it should be pointed out that *push-forward* is an operation applied to *measures*, rather than
*densities*.  If $\rho $ is a density (measurable, nonnegative function) on $\mathbb{R}^n$, then the associated measure
$\mu _\rho $ is defined for every measurable set $E\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ by
$$
  \mu _\rho (E) = \int_E\rho (x) dx.
  $$

Calling the push-forward measure $\nu $, we have by definition
$$
  \nu (E) =   \mu _\rho (f^{-1}(E)) = \int_{f^{-1}(E)}\rho (x) dx = \int_E\rho (f^{-1}(x))|J(f^{-1})(x)| dx,
  $$
by the change of variable formula,
where $J$ refers to the Jacobian.   In other words $\nu $ is the measure given by the density function
$$
  \tau (x)=\rho (f^{-1}(x))|J(f^{-1})(x)|,
  $$
so it is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure.

Needless to say, all of this requires $f$ to be smooth!  Otherwise strange things can happen:  there are homeomorphisms
of $\mathbb{R}$ which send a set of positive measure onto the Cantor set.  The push-forward of Lebesgue
measure (density 1) through such function assigns positive measure to the Cantor set, hence is clearly not absolutely continuous.

Comment: What's the weakest assumption on this smoothness? My guess is it has to have non-degenerate Jacobians and non-atomic but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3):

When you take a probability measure with a density w.r.t. Lebesgue measure, and push it forwards, you get a new probability measure, but this push-forward measure need not have  a density.  For the first claim here, look at the theorem recited in the wikipedia page you cite, in the special case of the function $g$ being the constant $1$. For the second claim here, let $H:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ be any strictly increasing no-where differentiable function, for which $H(0)=0$ and $H(1)=1$, and let $f$ be its inverse function.  If $X$ has uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ then $f(X)$ has $H$ as its cumulative distribution function, but (by hypothesis on $H$) has no density function.

Here is one class of examples of such $H$;  they are discussed in Billingsley's *Ergodic Theory* book.  Let $B_i$ be i.i.d. random bits, with $P(B_i=0)=1-p, P(B_i=1)=p$, where $0<p<1$ and $p\ne 1/2$.  Then $H(x)=P(\sum_{n>0} B_n 2^{-n}\le x)$ has the required properties.  (It is easy to plot the graph of $H$: you know $H(1/2)=1-p$, and you can fractally interpolate. Billingsley gives such a plot on p.37.)