# Understanding Probability Spaces

Tags: probability, statistics

I was looking at the following description of probability spaces, and was trying to understand this better:

[image]

In the example of flipping a coin, is the following correct?

- The sample space : Heads or Tails
- The event space: Some combination of outcomes you interested in observing (e.g. Heads, Heads, Tails)
- The probability function: In this example, the binomial probability distribution function

Is my understanding correct?

Thanks

Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_space

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the formal definition of "probability distribution"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3095900/what-is-the-formal-definition-of-probability-distribution)

Comment: No that’s not perfectly correct. I think you should use a more substantial experiment as your example, such as tossing a coin three times in a row.

Comment: thank you everyone for your replies - I am reading the link that Oliver Diaz posted!

Comment: Question similar to yours have been addressed before in MSE. I already sent a link to one that. You can find many more answers that may more satisfactory to you using [Aproach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=Markov%2C%20Chebyshev%2C%20%24%5C%20%5Cmu%5Cleft(%5Cright%7Cf%5Cleft%7C%3Et%5Cright)%5Cleq%5C%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bt%5Ep%7D%5Cint%20%20%5Cleft%7Cf%5Cright%7C%5E%7Bp%5C%20%7Dd%5Cmu%24&p=1) engine

Comment: OP is asking a specific question about a specific example, though; we should actually answer the specific question.

Comment: If you want $HHT$ to be an outcome or event, you may need to start with $\Omega=\{H,T\}^3$ and $\mathcal F=\mathcal P(\Omega)$

Answer (score 3):

You are correct about the sample space. We can take the sample space to be $\Omega = \{ H, T \}$.

The event space $\mathcal F$, however, should be the collection of all subsets of $\Omega$. In other words: $\mathcal F = \{ \emptyset, \{H\},\{T\},\{H, T \} \}$.

The probability function $P$ takes as input an event and returns as output the probability of that event. So, assuming the coin is fair:
\begin{align}
P(\emptyset) &= 0,\\
P(\{H\}) &= \frac12,\\
P(\{T\}) &= \frac12,\\
P(\{H, T \}) &= 1.
\end{align}

Comment: However this is basically never how probability theory is actually done in practice, so working it out is really not very instructive.

Comment: But if one is not able to work it out, that represents a genuine lack of understanding of the definition of a probability space. Part of learning to understand the definition of a probability space is thinking about what the probability space would be in simple examples like this.

Comment: In a way I disagree, I find these "build a suitable sample space" exercises are misleading to how people actually do things. It is more useful to have a strong sense of the things that can be done within the framework (e.g. iid sequences are possible, continuous time white noise is not) and treat how you get that back down to foundations as an enrichment exercise to me.

Comment: This is not a criticism of the answer (it answers the question that was asked). It is more a warning to the OP that this question might be less useful than they think it is.

Comment: I liked your answer. And I think it segues well into this more extensive post in [Cut The Knot](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Probability/SampleSpaces.shtml) by the late Alexander Bogomolny.